# How to add space between all children of div

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a styled div where I want some space between all the children. As the children can be any other component (buttons, divs, paragraphs, etc) in the project I can't add padding to those, so I want to find a way to do it from the styled div itself. There is also no telling how many children the div will have. Sometimes it can be empty, other times it can have three or four children.

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried several things, but so far nothing has worked.

This is the div as it is now:
(the esthetic styling is done in its parent)

```
const StyledBox = styled.div`
    float: right;
    min-width: 50px;
`
```

This div is part of Header

```
const StyledParent = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
`

const StyledBottom = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 65px;
`

const Header = (props) => {
    return (
        <StyledParent {...props}>
            <StyledTop {...props}>
            </StyledTop>
            <StyledBottom>
                <StyledBox {...props}></StyledBox>
            </StyledBottom>
        </StyledParent>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide working example of component.

Comment: give some ideal things you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could style any element inside your div by using the `*` css selector :

```
const Div = styled.div`
 * {
   //style applied to every elements
  }
`;
```

To add space after each of them, you could use the `after` pseudo-class like this:

```
const Div = styled.div`
  * {
    &::after {
      content: " "; //space inserted after each element
    }
  }
`
```